# Decorator using .apply(this, arguments) vs. returning the executed function

Tags: javascript, javascript-decorators

I'm learning decorators, and while I haven't been having good luck with tutorials, I tried to hack one myself and got this:

```js
function sum(...args) { return [...args].reduce((sum,a)=> sum + a, 0) }

const decorate = (fn, callback) => (...args) => {
        callback();
        return fn(...args); // Return the result of the executed function
}

const running = () => console.log('Running')
const decoratedSum = decorate(sum, running)
console.log(decoratedSum(1,2,3)) // 'Running' // 6
```

I still had a tutorial post opened and instead of executing the function using f(arg) they use f.apply():

```js
function sum(...args) { return [...args].reduce((sum,a)=> sum + a, 0) }

const wrap = (fn, callback) => function(){
        callback();
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
}

const running = () => console.log('Running')
const wrappedSum = wrap(sum, running)
console.log(wrappedSum(1,2,3)) // 'Running' // 6
```

Is there a reason **not** to use decorate() over wrap()?

Also can someone please explain what's actually happening with fn.apply(this, arguements)?

Comment: `apply` will preserve the value of `this` when called. Try `{ x: 40, foo: wrap( function() { return this.x + 2;  }, running ) }` https://jsbin.com/pirupigute/edit?js,console

Comment: Makes sense and very cool, thank you for the perfect example! Since there's always a (high) possibility that we'll decorate an object/class method, then I'll stick with apply then!